# Change Absolute picture size in Word Doc using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I have added picture to Word Doc as:

```
var app = new Word.Application();
DocForPrint = app.Documents.Add();
Range docRange = DocForPrint.Range();
Word.InlineShape picShape = docRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imgPath);
```

and now I want to change/set its **Absolute** size as in Word Editor

[image: absolute size of pic]

The thing is I cannot find if there is a property for it because

```
picShape.Width = 50;
```

seems to be pxl size.

Do you know how this could be done?

Comment: Do you have a Application.CentimetersToPoints(21.89) method? This is from VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Word is a word processor, many of the measurements it uses are in *points* - this is a printing measurement. Luckily, the Word application also provides conversion functions for points, pixels, centimeters and inches.

```
Word.Document DocForPrint = wdApp.Documents.Add();
Word.Range docRange = DocForPrint.Content;
Word.InlineShape picShape = docRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imgPath);
picShape.Width = wdApp.CentimetersToPoints(21.89f);
picShape.Height = wdApp.CentimetersToPoints(15.6f);
```